# Hide DIV when make selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 select.
If user submit form without dropdown selectioe, a message is displayed on a DIV.
There is a way to HIDE div (disappear?) when user select value?

SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#go").click(function () {

if (document.getElementById('sel').selectedIndex == 0)
$("#msg").html("Please select 1");


if (document.getElementById('sel2').selectedIndex == 0)
$("#msg2").html("Please select 2");

});
});
```

FORM:

```
<form id="form1">  
<div id="msg"></div>                  
<select id="sel">
<option value="">-- select --</option>
<option value="valor1">Valor 1</option>
<option value="valor2">Valor 2</option>
</select>

<div id="msg2"></div>
<select id="sel2">
<option value="">-- select --</option>
<option value="valor1">Valor 1</option>
<option value="valor2">Valor 2</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="go" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#go").click(function () {

if ($('#sel').val() == '')
    $("#msg").text("Please select 1");


if ($('#sel2').val() == '')
$("#msg2").text("Please select 2");

});
$('#sel').change(function(){$('#msg').hide()})
$('#sel2').change(function(){$('#msg2').hide()})
```

and working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RmYbH/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot Glen for your reply,

Answer (score 2):

What you can do it utilize the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event in jQuery. This allows you to watch for changes on a particular element such as the select element. I've made a [fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/atomicpages/FYyq4/). Sample code can be seen here:

```
$("#go").click(function () {
    if (document.getElementById('sel').selectedIndex == 0) $("#msg").html("Please select 1");
    if (document.getElementById('sel2').selectedIndex == 0) $("#msg2").html("Please select 2");
});

$('select').change(function() {
    if (document.getElementById('sel').selectedIndex != 0) $("#msg").fadeOut();
    if (document.getElementById('sel2').selectedIndex != 0) $("#msg2").fadeOut();
});
```

This should be a good starting point for you. Hope this helps!

Comment: djthoms, thanks for your reply...unfortunately you can not accept  2 answers.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to hide a div is using the CSS property display and setting it to none. In jQuery you can do this with the hide method, or manually via the css method.

```
$('#msg').hide();
$('#msg2').css('display','none');
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I missed the part where you needed help listening for the change event.